# Symfony 4.3 wrong translator locale on prod

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I've updated my web app from Symfony 4.1 to 4.3 and strange bug emerged. When on dev env, the translator is working correctly - it has locale set by request locale. But when I switch to prod env, the translator has always default locale regardless on request locale (see attached images).

The locale of the request is determined by subscribed event "onKernelRequest" with priority higher than "LocaleListener" according to [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html), see debug:

```
#8 App\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber::onKernelRequest() 20
#9 ApiPlatform\Core\Filter\QueryParameterValidateListener::onKernelRequest() 16        
#10 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest() 16
```

Can you suggest some things to check? With 4.1 it was working correctly.

It's not cache issue, I've tried clear cache gazillion times with both clear:cache and deleting cache folder contents. I've also tried this on localhost and remote server and the behavior is always the same (with cleared cache).

[image: DEV ENV]
[image: PROD ENV]

The locale of the translator should be set by request's locale in both dev and prod env. But it's working only on dev env.

Comment: check your locale param in the .yaml you have in dev and prod folder

Comment: @HéctorPrats thanks but it's not the case either, the locale is set across all environments the same. Default and fallback locale is 'en'.

Comment: Im sure not. Search in all your yaml where doy you have the 'cs' word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force the local in the translator:

```
App\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber::onKernelRequest
$translator->setLocale($locale);
```

Comment: Even though the method "setLocale" is no longer available in TranslatorInterface, the previous interface is still available (as deprecated), so I followed your advice and set the locale manually. I found that some other service is rewriting it back to "EN". After a while of debugging I found this "object normalizer", which was setting "en" to translator in constructor (for some export). It seems that in production mode of new Symfony, there is different order of instancing the services and this caused the issue. Thank you for help :)

Comment: @Vaca I have the same issue and neither this solution works for me nor I can find the object normalizer you just mentioned. I know this thread was for years ago but is it possible to give me some insights about this normalizer that always makes symfony load EN in production and test?

Comment: @TheDevWay I don't know if I remember it correctly, but I think the object normalizer was my class (not Symfony), which just transforms some data structure before it was send to API endpoint. The class was injecting the transaltor to constructor and setting harcoded "en" lang. I thing I've solved it by setting the the lang in the normalization method (instead of constructor) - make it "lazy". Try to search across your services (possibly all classes) to find any use of translator in constructors. If you find some, try to use it later in the code (not in the constructor).

Comment: @Vaca thanks for the answer. the thing is in our case, the translation works perfectly in development. but on our test build and prod build it just goes english no matter what locale is set. any idea what can cause this pain?

Comment: @TheDevWay I think your issue is same as mine. Ty to search across all your classes, where you injecting the translator and make sure you are not using it in the constructor. I think the case here is that in DEV env is different order of instancing some classes (due to caching) than in TEST and PROD env. If you are using the translator in constructor of any of your classes, you can experience different behavior in DEV and PROD.